# the combination of two independent continuous time Markov chains

Tags: markov-process

Assume one variable $x$ has two states 0 and 1, $x$ changes between 0 and 1 following a continuous time Markov chain. The transition probability is represented as matrix $P$ and the time sojourning on a state follows exponential distribution with arrival ratio $\lambda$.

There is the other variable y which is independent with $x$. $y$ also changes between 0 and 1, and have the same $P$ and $\lambda$ with $x$.

Now the question is: will the new variable $z=x*y$ follow continuous time Markov chain? if yes, what will be the transition probability and $\lambda$. ($z$ only has two states: 0 and 1.)

I guess $z$ still follows continuous time Markov chain, but I have no idea how to prove? (maybe there has been a property stating this, which I don't know?) Could anyone give some ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: What does $*$ represent?

Comment: "*" simplify means multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product $z_t$ is not a Markov Chain (MC).

Assume we know that $z_{t_0} = 0$ at
some time $t_0$, meaning that $x_{t_0}=0$ or $y_{t_0}=0$.  Then the
past values $\{z_{u};\,u <t_0\}$ of $z_t$ still contain information
about future values $\{z_v;\, v > t_0\}$ in contradiction with 
the Markov property.  Indeed, let $s_t := [x_t,
\,y_t]$; so that $s_t$ is a MC taking the $4$ values written here as $00$,
$01$, $10$ and $11$.  At time $t_0$, only the first $3$
states are possible since the product is $0$.  Let $t_0-W$ be the random time of the latest
state change for $z_t$, which was $z: \,1 \rightarrow 0$.  If $W$ is small,
then most probably $s_{t_0}$ is $01$ or $10$, but not
$00$: only one change of state occured during the interval
$(t_0-W, \,t_0)$. This in turn tells us that the next transition $0
\rightarrow 1$ will occur more quickly than if a large value $W$ had
been obtained.

Here is a more formal derivation. For a fixed $t$ and a small $h > 0$ we have
$$
  \mathrm{Pr}\{z_{t-h} = 1\,\vert \,s_{t} = 00\} = o(h),
  \qquad
  \mathrm{Pr}\{z_{t-h} = 1\,\,\vert \, s_{t} = 01\} = \lambda h + o(h)
$$
with $\lambda >0$. Indeed,  the first probability involves two transitions of $s_t$. 
Using Bayes formula
$$
  \mathrm{Pr}\{s_{t} = 00 \,\vert\, z_{t-h} = 1, \, z_{t}=0\} 
  = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}\{ z_{t-h} = 1 \,\vert \,s_{t} = 00\} \,
    \mathrm{Pr}\{  s_{t} = 00\, \vert \, z_{t} = 0\}}{ \mathrm{Pr}\{ z_{t-h} = 1 \,\vert \, z_{t} = 0 \} }.
$$
The numerator of the fraction is $o(h)$, while its denominator 
is easily found to be $\nu h + o(h)$ for some $\nu >0$, so the probability is $o(h)$. 
By contrast
$$
  \mathrm{Pr}\{s_{t} = 01 \,\vert\, z_{t-h} = 1, \, z_{t}=0\} 
  = \rho h + o(h)
$$
for some $\rho > 0$. Thus conditional on  $\{z_{t-h} = 1, \, z_{t}=0\}$
the event  $\{s_{t} = 01\}$ is much more probable than $\{s_{t} = 00\}$
for small $h$, as claimed.

Here $z_t$ follows a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) with hidden state $s_t$
and simply results from grouping $3$ possible states of $s_t$ as
one $z_t=0$.  More generally, grouping states of a MC $s_t$ will
result in a HMM process but not a MC.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is inspiriting! In a short saying against that z follows CTM, the next new state of z after t_0 is not only decided by the its state on t_0, but the transition process which leads to its state on t_0.

Comment: Happy if this helps... Yes, at $t_0$ the time spent in state $z=0$ contains information about how quickly we can leave it. One can draw a graph with the four states of $s_t$ as nodes and transitions as
arcs. Then $z_t=0$ means that $s_t$ is in the group of states $\{00,\,01, 10\}$. Within this group, $s_t$ can be one step away from
the exit $z =0 \rightarrow z=1$, or two steps away.

Comment: although z does't follow CTM, can it be modeled by some other models? I am now curious about the duty circle (the proportion of state 1 in a long duration) of z.

Comment: Since the two MC $x_t$ and $y_t$ are time homogeneous so is the MC $s_t$.  The time spent by $s_t$ in the state $11$, which is the time
spent by $z_t$ in state $1$,  can be computed using continuous MC theory. This 
imply: first writing the $4 \times 4$ generator matrix for $s_t$ using the
two rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$ for transitions $0 \rightarrow 1$
and $1 \rightarrow 0$, then find the stationnary distribution. 

From a more more statistical point a view, if only $z_t$ is observed,
inference on $x_t$ and $y_t$ can be drawn using HMM techniques
(Baum-Welch, Viterbi, ...).